# laravel guzzlehttp - Server Exception in RequestException.php

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle

I am getting ServerException in RequestException.php line 107 when I make POST request to my API. I get following error -
Server error: `POST http://10.10.1.40:3000/auth/register` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error response:
{"statusCode":500,"errorMessage":"[object Object]"}`.
I tried sending post request from REST Client and it works.
Following is the trace

```
in RequestException.php line 107 at RequestException::create(object(Request), object(Response)) in Middleware.php line 65
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199
at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise),   object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 152
at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60
at TaskQueue->run(true) in Promise.php line 240
at Client->request('POST', 'http://10.10.1.40:3000/auth/register', array('body' => '{"firstName":"abc","lastName":"ab"}')) in RegisterController.php line 30
at RegisterController->postRegisterForm(object(Request))
```

Following is my controller code

```
class RegisterController extends Controller{ 
    public function postRegisterForm(Request $request){ 
        $jsonData = json_encode($_POST);    
        $client = new Client(); 
        $res = $client->request('POST','10.10.1.40:3000/auth/register', ['body' => $jsonData]); 
        echo $res->getStatusCode();
        echo $res->getBody();   
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code for RegisterController ?

Comment: Post this in your question

Comment: my first guess would be that your server is not happy with the request it is being sent.  Usually requests are configured in such a way as to inform the server that the content-type is json.  What happens if you call $response = $client->request('POST', $uri, ['json'=>$jsonEncodableData, 'debug'=>true,]);

Comment: Is the server accepts port 3000? Send request without port. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right @ShaunBramley. I missed out sending the content type header in request. Adding following code works -

```
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
$res = $client->request('POST', 'http://10.10.1.40:3000/auth/register', ['headers'=>$headers,'body' => $jsonData]);
```