# Laravel 5.4 : 500 Internal Server Error when accessing localhost API

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, localhost, guzzle

i tried to call localhost API in my application using guzzle, but i got this error:

```
ServerException in RequestException.php line 111:
Server error: `GET http://localhost/WingsFeedAPI/public/products` resulted 
in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow (truncated...)
```

the API made with https://github.com/ellipsesynergie/api-response, and when i access http://localhost/WingsFeedAPI/public/products it returns :

```
// 20170517054157
// http://localhost/WingsFeedAPI/public/products

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nama_barang": "Daging ayam",
      "harga_barang": "5000",
      "rating": "123",
      "jenis_barang": "daging",
      "expired": "2017-05-03"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how i call that API in my application

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','http://localhost/WingsFeedAPI/public/products');
    echo $res->getBody();
}
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-51-guzzle-6-serverexception-in-middlewarephp-line-68-server-error-500?page=2); it requires the following steps;

The first one: to remove section below from the `.env` file,

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

The second one, to define in the `config/database.php` file the MySQL database parameters.

The snippet below highlights the portion to be edited for the database configuration a referred right above;

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel appears to be working fine.
See comments for discussion.

Comment: that's right. but i just want to display echo $res->getBody(), which it returns json data of my API, and i got the 500 internal server error.

Comment: Does guzzle require a header to be specified for Json data? like 
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];

Comment: Found a post related to this, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35402349/8005010

Comment: i dont know about that, i just tried using http://localhost/somejson.json before, and that work, but if i using http://localhost/WingsFeedAPI/public/products it returns error. Both files contain a same data

Comment: Can you access other pages from that directory? http://localhost/WingsFeedAPI/public/ ?

Comment: yes i can, i think the API works fine and the problem is on my application that calls the api or in the xampp configuration, but i have no idea about that

Comment: Laravel looks okay, I don't work with xampp, so that's out of my scope. Sorry I couldn't help you more. :/